# How to draw a GDI + text independent of DPI

Tags: text, gdi+, draw, dpi

I'm drawing a text using GDI+. I recently noticed that this text is automatically scaled when the DPI is changed. Is there a way to make the GDI+ text drawing independent of the DPI? E.g. I want to draw a text up to 20 pixels, regardless of the DPI. Is it possible? How to do this?

Below is a sample code. I want to draw the first text with a constant size, regardless of the DPI, and the second text normally:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        inherited::WndProc(message);

        Canvas->Brush->Style = bsSolid;
        Canvas->Brush->Color = clWhite;
        Canvas->FillRect(ClientRect);

        // get GDI+ graphics from canvas
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(Canvas->Handle);

        // set text rendering hint
        graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(Gdiplus::TextRenderingHintSystemDefault);

        std::auto_ptr<Gdiplus::Font>         pFont(new Gdiplus::Font(Canvas->Handle, Font->Handle));
        std::auto_ptr<Gdiplus::SolidBrush>   pBrush(new Gdiplus::SolidBrush(Gdiplus::Color(255, 0, 0, 0)));
        std::auto_ptr<Gdiplus::StringFormat> pFormat(new Gdiplus::StringFormat());

        Gdiplus::FontFamily fontFamily;
        pFont->GetFamily(&fontFamily);

        std::auto_ptr<Gdiplus::Font> pFont2(new Gdiplus::Font(&fontFamily, pFont->GetSize(),
                pFont->GetStyle(), Gdiplus::UnitPixel));
        Gdiplus::Unit test = pFont->GetUnit();
        Gdiplus::Unit test2 = pFont2->GetUnit();

        pFormat->SetAlignment(Gdiplus::StringAlignmentNear);
        pFormat->SetLineAlignment(Gdiplus::StringAlignmentNear);

        Gdiplus::StringFormatFlags flags = Gdiplus::StringFormatFlagsBypassGDI;
        //flags = (Gdiplus::StringFormatFlags)(flags | Gdiplus::StringFormatFlagsDirectionRightToLeft);
        //flags = (Gdiplus::StringFormatFlags)(flags | Gdiplus::StringFormatFlagsDirectionVertical);
        //flags = (Gdiplus::StringFormatFlags)(flags | Gdiplus::StringFormatFlagsNoWrap);
        //flags = (Gdiplus::StringFormatFlags)(flags | Gdiplus::StringFormatFlagsNoClip);
        pFormat->SetFormatFlags(flags);

        pFormat->SetTrimming(Gdiplus::StringTrimmingEllipsisCharacter);
        pFormat->SetHotkeyPrefix(Gdiplus::HotkeyPrefixNone);

        std::wstring text = L"This is a sample code";

        Gdiplus::Unit prevPageUnit = graphics.GetPageUnit();

        try
        {
            graphics.SetPageUnit(Gdiplus::UnitPixel);

            // draw text
            graphics.DrawString(text.c_str(), text.length(), pFont2.get(), Gdiplus::RectF(ClientRect.Left,
                    ClientRect.Top, ClientWidth, ClientHeight), pFormat.get(), pBrush.get());
        }
        __finally
        {
            graphics.SetPageUnit(prevPageUnit);
        }

        // draw text 2
        graphics.DrawString(text.c_str(), text.length(), pFont.get(), Gdiplus::RectF(ClientRect.Left,
                ClientRect.Top + 25, ClientWidth, ClientHeight), pFormat.get(), pBrush.get());

        return;
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to mention something, slightly unrelated to your question. You shouldn't be using `Graphics.DrawString` in GDI+ anymore. It was deprecated in .NET 2. Instead Microsoft created `TextRenderer.DrawString`.

There are two ways of drawing text in .NET:

- GDI+ (`graphics.MeasureString` and `graphics.DrawString`)
- GDI (`TextRenderer.MeasureText` and `TextRenderer.DrawText`)

In .NET 1.1 everything used **GDI+** for text rendering. [But there were some problems](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/05/19/gdi-vs-gdi-text-rendering-performance/):

> - There are some performance issues caused by the somewhat stateless nature of GDI+, where device contexts would be set and then the original restored after each call.
> - The shaping engines for international text have been updated many times for Windows/Uniscribe and for Avalon (Windows Presentation Foundation), but have not been updated for GDI+, which causes international rendering support for new languages to not have the same level of quality.

So they knew they wanted to change the .NET framework to stop using **GDI+**'s text rendering system, and use **GDI**. At first they hoped they could simply change:

```
graphics.DrawString
```

to call the old `DrawText` API instead of GDI+. But they couldn't make the text-wrapping and spacing match exactly as what GDI+ did. So they were forced to keep `graphics.DrawString` to call GDI+ (compatiblity reasons; people who were calling `graphics.DrawString` would suddenly find that their text didn't wrap the way it used to).

A new static `TextRenderer` class was created to wrap GDI text rendering. It has two methods:

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText
TextRenderer.DrawText
```

> **Note:**
>   - `TextRenderer` is a wrapper around GDI
>   - `graphics.DrawString` is still a wrapper around GDI+

---

Then there was the issue of what to do with all the existing .NET controls, e.g.:

- `Label`
- `Button`
- `TextBox`

They wanted to switch them over to use `TextRenderer` (i.e. GDI), but they had to be careful. There might be people who depended on their controls drawing like they did in .NET 1.1. And so was born "*compatible text rendering*".

By default controls in application behave like they did in .NET 1.1 (they are "*compatible*").

You **turn off** compatibility mode by calling:

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

This makes your application better, faster, with better international support. To sum up:

```
SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true)  SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)
=======================================  ========================================
 default                                  opt-in
 bad                                      good
 the one we don't want to use             the one we want to use
 uses GDI+ for text rendering             uses GDI for text rendering
 graphics.MeasureString                   TextRenderer.MeasureText
 graphics.DrawString                      TextRenderer.DrawText
 Behaves same as 1.1                      Behaves *similar* to 1.1
                                          Looks better
                                          Localizes better
                                          Faster
```

---

It's also useful to note the mapping between GDI+ `TextRenderingHint` and the corresponding [`LOGFONT` Quality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used for GDI font drawing:

```
TextRenderingHint           mapped by TextRenderer to LOGFONT quality
========================    =========================================================
ClearTypeGridFit            CLEARTYPE_QUALITY (5) (Windows XP: CLEARTYPE_NATURAL (6))
AntiAliasGridFit            ANTIALIASED_QUALITY (4)
AntiAlias                   ANTIALIASED_QUALITY (4)
SingleBitPerPixelGridFit    PROOF_QUALITY (2)
SingleBitPerPixel           DRAFT_QUALITY (1)
else (e.g.SystemDefault)    DEFAULT_QUALITY (0)
```

---

### Samples

Here's some comparisons of GDI+ (graphics.DrawString) verses GDI (TextRenderer.DrawText) text rendering:

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit`, **GDI**: `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY`:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintAntiAlias`, **GDI**: `ANTIALIASED_QUALITY`:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintAntiAliasGridFit`, **GDI**: *not supported, uses ANTIALIASED_QUALITY*:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintSingleBitPerPixelGridFit`, **GDI**: `PROOF_QUALITY`:

[image]

**GDI+**: `TextRenderingHintSingleBitPerPixel`, **GDI**: `DRAFT_QUALITY`:

[image]

i find it odd that `DRAFT_QUALITY` is identical to `PROOF_QUALITY`, which is identical to `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY`.

**See also**

- [UseCompatibleTextRendering - Compatible with whaaaaaat?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/10/13/480632.aspx)
- [Sorting it all out: A quick look at Whidbey's TextRenderer](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/27/432986.aspx)
- [MSDN: LOGFONT Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [AppCompat Guy: GDI vs. GDI+ Text Rendering Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/05/19/gdi-vs-gdi-text-rendering-performance.aspx)
- [GDI+ Text, Resolution Independence, and Rendering Methods.
  Or - Why does my text look different in GDI+ and in GDI?](http://windowsclient.net/articles/gdiptext.aspx)

Comment: I found this answer interesting.  The application I maintain is C++, Win32 based, and I'm using layered windows (for transparency over video).  I use Gdiplus.  TextRenderer is in System.Windows.Forms.  If it's bypass direct to GDI, does it support layered window transparency, etc.  Traditionally GDI itself did not understand the concept of alpha.

Comment: @Robinson Any pixels drawn on glass that are GDI "black" (`0x00000000`) will be rendered as transparent by the compositer. But beyond that, you have the `DrawThemeText`, which knows how to draw the *outer glow* around text on glass so that it remains readable, and uses partially alpha-transparent glow. But at the least you **cannot** use `ClearText` quality; but must must `AntiAlias`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me.

```
using namespace Gdiplus; 

HDC hDC = ::GetDC( NULL );
int nDPI = ::GetDeviceCaps( hDC, LOGPIXELSY );
::ReleaseDC( NULL, hDC );

REAL fFontHeight = 96 / (REAL)nDPI * 8;

FontFamily fontFamily( L"Arial" );
Gdiplus::Font font( &fontFamily, fFontHeight, UnitPixel );

REAL fMeasuredFontHeight = font.GetHeight( &gr );
```

It turns out that Gdiplus::Font, despite being specified in pixels, uses the user's DPI setting to adjust the resulting font (even when the font is to be used to draw in a bitmap!).  The standard DPI of 96 is a good value to use determine the correct ratio to adjust the font size.

In the above snippet, the font height sought was 8 pixels high.

fMeasuredFontHeight remains nearly constant (at approx. 12), through all DPI settings.